# Imagemagick file conversion not working?

Tags: bash, memory, conversion, imagemagick, gif

I am trying to convert a file from .gif to .bmp using this command:

```bsh
convert -coalesce pixels8.gif out.bmp
```

While doing this i get this error:

```bsh
convert-im6.q16: memory allocation failed `pixels8.gif' @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1303.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `out.bmp' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

---

I am not sure what the problem is. I have taken this command from https://github.com/glouw/paperview. My system has 8GB ram.

pixels8.gif:

```
Type: 'image/gif'  
Size: 4.6 MB (46,42,849 bytes)  
Resolution: 1920x1080
```

Comment: Did you try to invert the order? `convert pixel8.gif -coalesce test2.gif`, then if it works, with final picture in BMP format. Life is not commutative, imagemagick too. It you have problem with memory you can add the option `-layers optimize `.  ps> Welcome (out) on SuperUser. Let us know...